# React-bootstrap : How to put an intial value from a state to an inupt Form

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm trying to refactor a project with react-bootstrap but I have a Shity problem that I can't resolve...

I don't know how to put a default value with my state to the Input form...

I isolated a code example :

[My code example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6A4FQ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured out...

The value as be on the <Form.Control /> ...

Correction :

```
<Form.Control type="text" value={name} />
```

Thx anyway